# Как отфильтровать таблицу по номерам телефонов и привести их к одному виду?

Tags: python, excel, vba

Имеется таблица, в одной из её колонок указаны номера телефонов. (Нарсил из ВК.) Поэтому встречаются как пустые ячейки так и следующее:

```
11
893421
222
3428240
910 110 10 10
9999999999
89991112233
+79992223311
8-920-200-11-11
8(902)31-31-211
```

и т.д.

Как отфильтровать по маске номера, чтобы остались и те, что начинаются с кода `(9**)*** ** **` и с `+7` и с `8`, а также отфильтрованные номера привести к одному виду, убрать лишние символы?

Номера вида `:1`; `22`; `333`; `4444`; `55555`; `666666`; `7777777`; `88888888` - удалить номера вида: `999 999 99 99`; `+7999-999-99-99`; `89999999999` (там очень много вариантов разделителей и лишних символов) оставить и привести к единому виду `89999999999` или `+79999999999`.

Comment: приведите пример того, что вы хотите получить на выходе

Comment: номера вида :1 ; 22 ;333;4444;55555;666666;7777777;88888888 - удалить
номера вида: 999 999 99 99 ; +7999-999-99-99; 89999999999 (там очень много вариантов разделителей и лишних символов) оставить и привести к единому виду 89999999999 или +79999999999

Comment: вы все еще не указали пример выходного "data set"... Какое минимальное число цифр должно присутствовать в номере? какие еще правила фильтрации и преобразований?

Comment: Первая часть фильтруется regex, при чем фигурные скобки фиксируют глубину. Например для начала можно так `[0-9-() ]{7,15}` отфильтровать возможные символы, а потом сверху так `[0-9]{7,12}` отфильтворать только длинные номера. А уже на остаток можно наложить ещё фильтр. Например сделать тест на `(0{5,12})|(1{5,12})|` сделать тест на повторы. Ну и можно сделать ещё тесты на остатке, например тест на 12345. В один шаг незнаю можно ли отфильтровать.

Comment: @MaxU на выходе должна получиться та же таблица (с теме же стобцами) минимально количество цифр в номере 10 
так же чтобы остались номера начинающиеся на 8 и на +7, так же не должно быть никаких скобок , запятых и прочего мусора , только цифры без пробелов и каки-либо разделителей

Comment: @nick_n_a можно потробнее ? где и как использовать эти регулярки ?

Comment: Почитайте "регулярки в питоне".

Comment: Почитайте "регулярки в питоне". Хотя... чего это я... обычным циклом `for` эта задача будет решена гораздо оптимальнее чем регулярками...

Comment: Правильно ли: унифицированный номер - 11 цифр с первой 7 или 8; если 7, добавить слева плюс === Еще вопрос: если номер из 10 цифр, в каком случае добавлять 7, в каком 8?

Comment: @vikttur можно без плюса, мне главное отсортировать базу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение с использованием Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

# читаем Excel в Pandas DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\download\1.xlsx', dtype={'mobile_phone':'str'})

# удаляем все "не цифры"
df['mob_clean'] = df.mobile_phone.str.replace(r'\D','')

# маска фильтра: выбираем номера, в которых минимум 10 цифр
# и которые начинаются на `7` или `8`
mask = (df['mob_clean'].str.len() >= 10) & (df['mob_clean'].str.contains(r'^[78]'))

# заменяем "неправильные" номера на пустую строку
df.loc[~mask, ['mob_clean']] = ''

# сохраняем DataFrame в Excel файл
df.to_excel(r'c:/temp/result.xlsx', index=False)
```

пример результата:

```
In [26]: df.loc[mask, ['mobile_phone','mob_clean']]
Out[26]:
                  mobile_phone    mob_clean
83                  7900000000   7900000000
84                  7917589814   7917589814
85                  7954849615   7954849615
86                  8296186112   8296186112
87                  8495952372   8495952372
88                  8800535355   8800535355
89                  8800553535   8800553535
...                        ...          ...
2256           8-985-186-96-01  89851869601
2257           8-985-186-96-01  89851869601
2262               8987564589*   8987564589
2266           8-999-876-88-77  89998768877
2310       HOTLINE-89152431419  89152431419
2450          Viber89263674045  89263674045
2452  WhatsApp +7-977-847-8024  79778478024

[1571 rows x 2 columns]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на *VBA*, без регулярок

В первом цикле удаляется мусор в целом диапазоне. Это для того, чтобы ускорить чистку каждого значения.

Строка удаления лишних данных закомментирована, вместо нее - заливка неправильных данных.

```
Sub UnificationOfNumbers()
Dim aSymb()
Dim rData As Range, rDel As Range, c
Dim sStr As String
Dim lRw As Long, j As Long
    aSymb = Array("~*", "~?", " ", "(", ")", "-", "_", "/", ".", ",", "@", "x", ",", "^")

    With ActiveSheet
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row: If lRw < 2 Then Exit Sub
        Set rData = .Range("F2:F" & lRw)
    End With

    For j = 0 To UBound(aSymb)
        rData.Replace What:=aSymb(j), Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
    Next j

    For Each c In rData
        sStr = ""

        For j = 1 To Len(c.Value)
            If IsNumeric(Mid$(c.Value, j, 1)) Then 
                sStr = sStr & Mid$(c.Value, j, 1)
            End If
        Next j

        If Len(sStr) < 10 Or Len(sStr) > 11 Then
            If rDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rDel = c
            Else
                Set rDel = Union(rDel, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c

'    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete'
    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.Interior.Color = vbRed
    Set rData = Nothing: Set rDel = Nothing
End Sub
```